# Multiple if conditions for ad code

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set multiple conditions to display my ad code, but don't know how to combine the statements. Here is the first chunk, which ensures that the ad code doesn't show up on mobile devices:

```
<?php if (function_exists('wpmd_is_notdevice') && wpmd_is_notdevice()) :?>
MY AD CODE
 <?php else : ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

The second conditional is so that the ad code on displays on pages and posts that belong to the "blog" category:

```
<?php if (in_category ('blog')) {  ?>
MY AD CODE
<?php } ?>
```

Can someone please help me combine these two statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if (function_exists('wpmd_is_notdevice')
             && wpmd_is_notdevice()
             && in_category('blog')) :?>
  // YOUR AD CODE
 <?php endif; ?>
```